# python string index out of range

Tags: python, string

Ok. So I am probably the most stupidest person on this planet, but can someone tell me why this gives me an error (The program is for searching a character in an alphabetically ordered string of characters using bisection search):

```
def isInIter(char, aStr):
  print('char :'+char)
  print('aStr :'+aStr)
  isin = False
  while(len(aStr) > 0):
    if aStr[len(aStr)/2] == char:
      isin = True
      break
    else:
      if aStr[len(aStr)/2] > char:
        aStr = aStr[0 : len(aStr)/2]
        continue
      if aStr[len(aStr)/2] < char:
        aStr = aStr[(len(aStr)/2 + 1) :]
        continue
return isin
```

Error:

```
isInIter('d','cddfggjkkqtwyy')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-1de0eb4793fd> in <module>()
----> 1 isInIter('d','cddfggjkkqtwyy')

/home/user/Study/Ex/lec5_BisectionSearch.py in isInIter(char, aStr)
      5   isin = False
      6   while(len(aStr) > 0):
----> 7     if aStr[len(aStr)/2] == char:
      8       isin = True
      9       break

IndexError: string index out of range
```

But this works as expected:

```
char = raw_input('char :')
aStr = raw_input('aStr :')

isin = False
while(len(aStr) > 0):
 if aStr[len(aStr)/2] == char:
  isin = True
  break
 else:
  if aStr[len(aStr)/2] > char:
    aStr = aStr[0 : len(aStr)/2]
    continue
  if aStr[len(aStr)/2] < char:
    aStr = aStr[len(aStr)/2 + 1 :]
    continue

print isin
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: you can directly search without looping it. Python provides you 'in' keyword which helps you to search for a item. You can use "if char in string" in a single statement which tells you if char is present in string or not..

Comment: isInIter('d','cddfggjkkqtwyy') doesn't give error for me ? and works fine ?

Comment: that looks like a very bad way to search a character but your code runs just fine on my machine

Comment: You are returning the value at the wrong place.Check-out your code again and be sure that your line indentations are correct !

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is a homework problem for a MOOC course that I'm taking. The requirement is to implement the thing using a bisection search, not any other methods.

Comment: yes but it works very well after u correct your indentations as suggested by myildirim

Comment: Thanks myildirim. Must always check indentation. This will be a pain in large programs I guess.

Comment: @kchak Slicing the string creates a copy of the sliced part, so in a real application one would just keep track of the upper and lower index.  `isin` can be removed if you immediately `return True` if the character is found and `return False` at the end of the program.  The `continue` statements are unnecessary if you change the second `if` there into an `elif`.  Maybe it would be a good idea to keep all three cases on one level anyway with `if`/`elif`/`else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When python goes through a while loop, it waits until the end of the loop to check the exit criteria. It might be easier if you condense your function:

```
def isItIn(streen,carroter):
  while len(streen)>0:
    if streen[len(streen)/2]==carroter:
       return True
    if streen[len(streen)/2]>carroter:
       streen=streen[0:len(streen)/2]
    if len(streen)==0:return False
    if streen[len(streen)/2]<carroter:
        streen=streen[len(streen)/2+1:]

print isItIn('asdilk','a')
print isItIn('kdsoe','a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`str.index(sub\[, start\[, end\]\])`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)? You can bet that it has an optimized implementation.

```
In [1]: s = "cddfggjkkqtwyy"

In [2]: s.index("d")
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: s.index("d") > -1
Out[3]: True
```